# PHP, url rewriting with htaccess, and Microsoft IIS Url Rewriting?

Tags: iis, php, .htaccess, rewrite

I am used to working with Apache servers, so when mod_rewrite is enabled, I can create an htaccess file and use url rewriting.

Here's my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

now I've built this site that uses this url rewriting module but I have come to learn that it is a microsoft server. Can I use my htaccess file? Is there something I need to change to get it to work? How can I tell if url rewriting is set up on the microsoft server?

**Update:** Is there a free version that I can install that works with htaccess files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ISAPI-Rewrite 3](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/) from HeliconTech has very Apache-like syntax. The above config will work in ISAPI_Rewrite3 .htaccess without any modifications.

Answer (score 3):

You can [import Apache mod_rewrite rules](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/470/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules/) (not all of them, mind you) into the Microsoft URL rewriting engine for IIS7.

You can also install [Ionics Isapi Rewrite Filter](http://www.codeplex.com/IIRF), an open-source mod_rewrite-alike for IIS 6 and 7.  Another poster linked Helicon, which is similar, but costlier.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, IIS does not come with re-writing abilities out of the box. When we need to re-write, we use [ISAPI Re-Write from HeliconTech](http://www.isapirewrite.com/). It's not free, but it is very cheap.

It will give you a file called httpd.ini  - you put it in the root of your site like you would a .HTACCESS and it does the rest.

The format of the file is different, but it isn't *that* different.

Answer (score 0):

THe isapi filters mentioned should work fine.  You can also use [urlrewriting.net](http://www.urlrewriting.net/149/en/home.html) or [UrlRewriter.NET](http://urlrewriter.net/) if you want to take the time to go .net.   Both are free and will avoid the ISAPI filter hit. Your best option however is the [IIS 7 URL rewrite module](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-url-rewrite-module/)

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](http://www.micronovae.com/ModRewrite/ref/Compatibility.html) some information about IIS Mod-Rewrite from micronovae. I'm just starting to learn about it after discovering that CrystalTech uses it. It's a little more expensive than ISAPI_Rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

[IIRF](http://iirf.codeplex.com) (Ionic's ISAPI Rewrite Filter) will work with that .htaccess file, unchanged.  Well, you have to rename it.

There are some features that Apache's mod-rewrite has that IIRF does not, but your .htaccess file will work with no changes.

Answer (score 0):

Since I was running my WordPress blog (blog.jaspio.net) on a cheap IIS host, I wasn't allowed to install an ISAPI filter.

I then came across Tom Bristol's [great little ASP script](http://www.keyboardface.com/IIS-Permalinks/) to parse the .htaccess file to ensure that I had nice clean SEO links instead of querystrings.

Give it a go!