# Need IIS 6 URL Rewriting help

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6, rewrite

I know it's easy in IIS7 but unfortunately I'm running IIS 6 on Windows Server 2003. Can anyone give me a quick lesson on this?

Comment: See: http://serverfault.com/questions/143442/using-iis-url-rewrite-how-to-rewrite-foo-bar-com-bar-com-myapp or http://serverfault.com/questions/61501/is-there-a-isapi-filter-that-can-rewrite-the-header-values-before-passing-to-asp or http://serverfault.com/questions/30001/php-url-rewriting-with-htaccess-and-microsoft-iis-url-rewriting or http://serverfault.com/questions/142201/configure-iis-to-rewrite-ip-address-to-site-name

Answer (score 1):

Try [urlrewriter.net](http://urlrewriter.net/). I used it at a company where I was helping develop a social networking site.

Answer (score 0):

[Helicon ISAPI Rewrite](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/) is pretty much the defacto standard for IIS 6 rewriting. v3 even supports `.htaccess` syntax.

In fact I just purchased another server license for it this morning. (Don't stress, there are free versions)